# Mongodb: Determining shard key strategy on compound index

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-3.4

I have a collection with `170 millions+` documents and it is only going
 to increase. The size of the collection is not that huge, currently
 around `70 GB`.

The collection has two fields **indexed on: {AgentId:1, PropertyId:1}**.
 Generally one imports a huge file(millions of documents) belonging to
 a particular **AgentId but the PropertyId(non numeric nullable) is
 mostly random unique value.**

Currently I have **two shards with shard key based on {_id: hashed}**. But
 I am planning to **change the shard key to  compound Index {AgentId:1,
PropertyId:1}** because I think it will improve query performance( most
of the queries are based on AgentId filter). Not sure whether one can
have a `nullable` field in the `shard key`. If this is the case then app
 will make sure that the PropertyId is `random no`.

**So looking to get a picture as to**

1. How the data will be distributed to shards during insertion
    and how the range of a chunks are calculated during insertion?
2. Since the PropertyId is `random value`. Does the `compound key` fits the 
     definition of monotonically increasing value?

I am a newbie to MongoDB. And wanted to know if I am on the right path?

Comment: if the queries are mainly on AgentId only then they will be distributed to appropriate shard that houses the chunks for that AgentId.  Aren't there queries based on property id also?  As far as writes, if you get all writes for specific agentId at once then they will all go to the same shard (imagine the most trivial case of having exactly two agent id values and two shards - each shard would house one of the two agent ids).

Comment: Thanks Asya. Yes I have a group by on agentid,propertyid. And most of the queries are on AgentId with other filters. I am starting to get the picture as to how this chunking and balancer works. Since this is the case of bulk loading, I think I need to pre-split to properly distribute the writes and avoid unncecessary. splitting and migration. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports compound indexes, where a single index structure holds references to multiple fields ( As [MongoDB Limits and Thresholds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Number-of-Indexed-Fields-in-a-Compound-Index) MongoDB imposes a **limit of 31 fields** for any compound index.) within a collection’s documents. The following diagram illustrates an example of a compound index on two fields:

[image]

> How the data will be distributed to shards during insertion and how
>   the range of a chunks are calculated during insertion?

Starting in version 2.6, MongoDB can use  [index intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/) to fulfill queries. The choice between creating compound indexes that support your queries or relying on index intersection depends on the specifics of your system.

Index intersection does not eliminate the need for creating [compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/). However, because both the list order (i.e. the order in which the keys are listed in the index) and the sort order (i.e. ascending or descending), matter in [compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/), a compound index may not support a query condition that does not include the [index prefix keys](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#compound-index-prefix) or that specifies a different sort order.

For example, if a collection orders has the following compound index, with the status field listed before the ord_date field:

```
{ status: 1, ord_date: -1 }
```

The compound index can support the following queries:

```
db.orders.find( { status: { $in: ["A", "P" ] } } )
db.orders.find(
   {
     ord_date: { $gt: new Date("2014-02-01") },
     status: {$in:[ "P", "A" ] }
   }
)
```

But not the following two queries:

```
db.orders.find( { ord_date: { $gt: new Date("2014-02-01") } } )
db.orders.find( { } ).sort( { ord_date: 1 } )
```

However, if the collection has two separate indexes:

```
{ status: 1 }
{ ord_date: -1 }
```

The two indexes can, either individually or through index intersection, support all four aforementioned queries.

> Since the PropertyId is random value. Does the compound key fits the
>   definition of monotonically increasing value?

For the fastest processing, ensure that your indexes fit entirely in **RAM** so that the system can avoid reading the index from `disk`.

To check the size of your indexes, use the [db.collection.totalIndexSize()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.totalIndexSize/#db.collection.totalIndexSize) helper, which returns data in bytes:

```
> db.collection.totalIndexSize() 
4294976499
```

The above example shows an index size of almost `4.3 gigabytes`. To ensure this index fits in **RAM**, you must not only have more than that much **RAM** available but also must have RAM available for the rest of the [working set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-working-set).

If you have and use multiple collections, you must consider the size of all indexes on all collections. The indexes and the working set must be able to fit in memory at the same time.

For further your ref [Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/)

Comment: index intersection is not relevant to the question asked at all.  the question is about targeting of reads and writes to shards based on what the shard key is.